# What happened to the reliability thingie that was in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, performance-monitoring

Vista had this reliability monitor tool [Jeff talked about on coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001235.html) but now in Windows 7 there is something called reliability monitor that is different and stupid. How do you get the good one back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Start Menu, right click on Computer, and select "Manage".

Under "System Tools" click "Performance". That page will display a list of performance counters, as well as a link to the "Resource Monitor". This contains the exact same information as what you linked from the coding horror post, in a slightly different layout.

[image]

The Reliability Monitor is something completely different, which tracks system events in a graphical format on your PC. This can easily be accessed by clicking Start, and typing reliability, then click "View Reliability History" when it appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In what way is the Windows 7 one different and stupid? Have you had a look at [Resource Monitor](http://community.winsupersite.com/blogs/paul/archive/2008/10/31/windows-7-factoid-improved-resource-monitor.aspx) in Windows 7 I think that might be what you are looking for.

I haven't used Vista for years but they may have separated Reliability Monitor from Resource Monitor in Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 version also has a few spiffs over the Vista version, such as Total B/s when sorting on the Disk access, as opposed to just having the Read and Write totals in Vista.